# Unnecessary dependencies when bundling javafx application with maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, javafx-8

I am building a JavaFX application with maven, using the javafx maven plugin. Now when I execute `mvn jfx:jar`, it copies a lot of unnecessary jars into the resulting `lib` dir, like:

- `ant-1.8.2.jar`
- `maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.jar`
- `maven-plugin-api-2.0.11.jar`

and many more. So, it's basically everything I use for *compiling* the application - but it's certainly not needed for *running* it. I feel like I should add a `<scope>compile</scope>` somewhere in the POM, but the `<plugin>` element doesn't take one as child. How can I tell maven not to include the plugins I use for compilation in the lib directory created with `mvn jfx:jar`?

**Edit:** here's the POM if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.flyx.dsa.heldendokument</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>gui</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>gui</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flyx.dsa.heldendokument</groupId>
        <artifactId>generator</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.20.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.flyx.dsa.heldendokument.gui.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.flyx.dsa.heldendokument.gui.App</mainClass>
                    <appName>DSA Heldendokument-Generator</appName>
                    <needMenu>false</needMenu>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>aboutWindow.fxml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>aboutWindow.fxml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet for your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your pom.xml, maybe this already works when you upgrade the plugin-version to current 8.1.5 ?!

To make sure where some dependency come from, please call `mvn dependency:tree`, maybe it's your own dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flyx.dsa.heldendokument</groupId>
    <artifactId>generator</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

What confuses me: why are you putting "pluginManagement" inside your build instead just "plugins"?